# Oil in coolant after gasket work 1995 Chevrolet Lumina

Tags: oil, coolant

I had a coolant leak that turned out to be a bad gasket. Coolant was leaking into the motor. I had the gasket replaced, and was told to change the oil after a few hundred miles. When I did, it turned out that there was a lot of oil in the coolant. Shouldn't the mechanic who changed the gasket noticed this?

Comment: What gasket was changed?

Answer (score 3):

If coolant is getting into the engine, then oil will be getting into the coolant.  It's a 2-way street there.  I'm really surprised he didn't mention it, since it's expected.  However, normally after doing a gasket repair of that type they just automatically change your coolant and oil on the spot since it's contaminated.

Comment: I agree. I am surprised he didn't flush both.